# First time pc build trying to install ubuntu and struggling

Tags: boot

G3258 CPU, Msi Z97 pc mate, Evga GeForce 210, Evga 400w power source, 4gb Kingston 1333 ram, HD seagate-barracuda-1tb-7200rpm-64mb

I'm using a 2gb usb (fat) to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS the file is an ISO The bios/uefi is version E7850 IMS V4.7 I've selected the usb with the ISO file as the boot location Boot mode is legacy+uefi

I've gotten the erno 5 error An error that states there's an input output issue And once I was left hanging on a Pink and violet screen.

All these errors happen during the installation process just after the screen where you enter your name and choose a password immediately after it crashes.

I have not partitioned anything mainly because I don't know how to
Any help would be appreciated. I Don't have a cd/DVD drive just usb. Keep in mind it's my first build and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO?   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM    Have you done the media-check and memory check?  Have you tried the "try" option?

Comment: Try option works i can go in and even use the internet. Just cant install i don't know what hashcheck or media/memory check is im googling this right now